# Push data to parent controller from child [angularjs]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was trying to push cities object to array in a parent controller. The reply is "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". Anyway to solve this?

The ChildCtrl is nested inside the ParentCtrl.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="citieApp">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
      {{cites to be listed here ON UPDATE from the child controller}}


      <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
        <form>
          <!--This inputs are to insert cities-->
          <input type="text">
          <input type="text">
          <input type="text">
          <button>Submit Cities</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.cities = [{
    america: [{
      'alberta', 'NY', 'chicago', 'LA'
    }, {
      'atlanta', 'New town', 'boston', 'boulder'
    }, {
      'dallas', 'austin', 'denver', 'colombus'
    }]
  }, {
    europe: [{
      'london', 'paris', 'Helsinki'
    }, {
      'berlin', 'rome', 'tallin'
    }, {
      'lisbon', 'amsterdam', 'brussels'
    }]
  }];
};

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.cities.europe.push({
    'barcelona', 'madrid', 'manchester'
  });
}
```

I was trying to push cities object to array in a parent controller. The reply is "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". Anyway to solve this?

Comment: How do the 2 controllers interact (i.e. one view nested in another, a child modal opened from parent controller, etc)?

Comment: The child view is nested inside the parent.

Comment: Please post your markup. It's important to be able to see how the directives are nested to understand why this property of $scope is not inherited.

Comment: I was just typing that very remark @JoeHawkins

Comment: The skeleton structure of the html looks like above. As I said before, the view that is controlled by the ChildCtrl is inside the div of ParentCtrl

Comment: This has been answered an inordinate amount of times. just search communicating between controllers...

Answer (score 0):

Try to access it via $parent.

```
function ChildCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.$parent.cities.europe.push({
    'barcelona', 'madrid', 'manchester'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
  function ParentCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.cities = [{
         america: [{
            'alberta', 'NY', 'chicago', 'LA'
         }, {
            'atlanta', 'New town', 'boston', 'boulder'
          }, {
            'dallas', 'austin', 'denver', 'colombus'
          }]
       }, {
          europe: [{
             'london', 'paris', 'Helsinki'
           }, {
         'berlin', 'rome', 'tallin'
         }, {
            'lisbon', 'amsterdam', 'brussels'
        }]
  }];
};
```

Here,

```
 $scope.cities[0] = {
         america: [{
            'alberta', 'NY', 'chicago', 'LA'
         }, {
            'atlanta', 'New town', 'boston', 'boulder'
          }, {
            'dallas', 'austin', 'denver', 'colombus'
          }]
       };


  $scope.cities[1] = {
        {
          europe: [{
             'london', 'paris', 'Helsinki'
           }, {
         'berlin', 'rome', 'tallin'
         }, {
            'lisbon', 'amsterdam', 'brussels'
        }]
   };
```

But in your **clild Controller** you use ::

```
   function ChildCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.cities.europe.push({
         'barcelona', 'madrid', 'manchester'
      });
   }
```

you **push** data into `europe` object, but `europe` object is not available in `$scope.cities`. you can change your `$scope.cities` as like as given below:

```
  $scope.cities = {
         america: [{
            'alberta', 'NY', 'chicago', 'LA'
         }, {
            'atlanta', 'New town', 'boston', 'boulder'
          }, {
            'dallas', 'austin', 'denver', 'colombus'
          }], {
          europe: [{
             'london', 'paris', 'Helsinki'
           }, {
              'berlin', 'rome', 'tallin'
           }, {
            'lisbon', 'amsterdam', 'brussels'
          }]
  };
```